# How/why does this noise function work?

Tags: algorithms, random

How/why does this noise function work?

```
function noise(x)
    x = (x << 13) ^ x;
    return (1.0 - ((x * (x * x * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589) & 0x7fffffff)
               / 1073741824.0);
```

I've found it in several places with different primes, but couldn't find an actual explanation of why/how it works.

I know what the code itself is doing (shift, xor, multiply-and-overflow, bitwise-and w/ intmax - 1, etc), but I don't get why those things are done or how it results in acceptable noise.

Why are these operations, why this order? Why primes? I know "because non-primes can generate observable patterns", but why is that?

Why divide by (2**32 - 1)/2? or rather, why does that give a 0..2 value?

Comment: What is a noise function, and what does it mean for a noise function to work?

Comment: Looks like some kind of a PRNG to me. I'm not sure that there is much theory behind this. I added a *random* tag to attract people who might be more knowledgeable. That 0x7ff... is $2^{31}-1$ and the divisor is $2^{30}$. Therefore the result is 1.0-something, with something in the interval $[0,2)$. So (barring a mistake) the values $\in(-1,1]$.

Comment: I suppose the word 'noise' is used here in the sense of 'white-noise' process.  It seems some kind of pseudo-random number generator

Comment: `I've found it in several places` Where?

Comment: @leonbloy here's one page: http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm

Answer (score 3):

The function spreads the information contained in the input value across the full 32 bits, then scales it down to the range $-1..1$.

This first part makes the input affect both lower and higher bits:

```
x = (x << 13) ^ x;
```

Then that information is spread across the available domain (32 bits) by multiplying and adding it to three constants of different magnitudes - one small, one medium and one large:

```
digest = x * (x * x * 15731 + 789221) + 1376312589
```

Finally, the "random" integer is scaled down. `0x7fffffff` is $2^{31}$, so the bitwise *AND* operation makes sure the number is in the range $0..2^{31}$. `1073741824` is $2^{30}$, and $2^{31} \div 2^{30} = 2$, so after the division the range will be $0..2$. Subtracting from $1$ shifts the range to be $-1..1$.

```
return 1.0 - ((digest & 0x7fffffff) / 1073741824.0);
```

I'm not sure why the constants need to be prime. Perhaps primes have better bit patterns for this kind of thing.

It's worth noting that the result of this function will be different in different programming languages. It's very likely that there will be an integer overflow, which is language-dependent [even for unsigned 32-bit integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). In Python3 the number may be promoted to have more than 32 bits, so it will give *some* result even though there will be no overflow (but overflow might be desirable to increase randomness). In JavaScript the function fails completely for large numbers, because the bitwise *AND* always results in 0 for very large numbers (in my tests).

Answer (score 1):

It is a random noise generator. Did Google search on:
"noise function" 0x7fffffff

See:
http://www.qwerty-games.com/viewvc/Sardon3D/Branches/Networking/src/Noise.cpp?view=markup

http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/noisegen/index.html