Old math, new applications
I am looking for examples of how "old" math that was (likely) developed without any applications in mind has found a new life in unexpected settings. Particular theorems would be best. Some examples are Euler's Theorem and its role in cryptography, Perron-Frobenius Theorem and its application to Google PageRank algorithm, and Steiner's Isoparametric Inequality and its use in detecting gerrymandering.

This question has been asked in numerous places, including here.  See the page https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486855/what-are-some-examples-of-mathematics-that-had-unintended-useful-applications-mu
